# Adding array values to a sorted array in C

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

I am measuring Aavin[4] (5 voltage values) in an Array. For every aavin I also measure At[4] (Temperature values). Now to make a calibration function I have to sort the Aavin values from the biggest number to the smallest, but the Temperature varies so I cannot sort it.

I use qsort for aavin. The problem is, when I measured f.e. Aavin[0] = 1; At[0] = 1 and sort the Aavin Array, At[0] will no more be the temperature from Aavin[0] since Aavin[0] is now f.e. Aavin[3].

Does somebody have any idea how I could sort At[] so the value in the column is matched to the column of the sorted Aavin[] array? Or maybe stick the Values of At[] to the associated Aavin[]?

Here is my code:

```
void sortier(){

qsort(mess.Aavin, 4, sizeof(double),cmpfunc);

//qsort(kali.ApH, 4, sizeof(double),cmpfunc);
}
```

Here is the problem with the At:

```
sortier();

for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) && (int a = 4; i>0, i--){
    mess.stc[i] = ((mess.Aavin[a] - mess.Uref) - (mess.Aavin[a-1] - mess.Uref))
            / (kali.ApH[a] - kali.ApH[a-1]);//pHA von simon *******************************
    mess.tcal[i] = (mess.At[a] + 273.1 + mess.At[a-1] + 273.1) / 2;
    mess.Stcal[i] = (double) mess.stc[i] / mess.tcal[i];
}
}
```

Comment: Define a `struct` that has both an Aavin value and the corresponding At value. Then make and sort a single array of those structs (or pointers to those structs). For more specific help please provide complete code as a [mre].

Comment: What is `mess` ? A struct of some sort ? Post it

Answer (score -1):

Don't sort the array itself, sort a new array with indexes...

```
int Aavin[4] = {2, 6, 3, 1};
int At[4] = {12, 16, 13, 11};
int indexes[4] = {0, 1, 2, 3};

// sort indexes ==> indexes = {1, 2, 0, 3}
// cannot use qsort (unless you make Aavin a global array [don't do that])
// write your own sort function
for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
    printf("%d, %d\n", Aavin[indexes[k]], At[indexes[k]]);
}
```